# Applying HDR (high dynamic range) rendering in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, remote-sensing, rendering, digital-image-processing

I want to **automatically** (without manual adjustments) apply HDR (high dynamic range) rendering to Sentinel-2 satellite images so that the image can distinguish between very bright objects (e.g. clouds, sand) and very dark objects (e.g. objects obscured by cloud shadows).
In wikipedia I found an example of applying this technology to an image:

[image]

The current QGIS 3 rendering settings do not allow to achieve such a result even with the `Statistic extent` option set to `Updated canvas` ([Example Sentinel-2 raster.tif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YofanStQz2-bwCW_1pUCKUX1y9vbGql-/view?usp=sharing)):

[image] ==> [image]

Gamma correction:
[image]

**Does the current version of QGIS have plugins or settings to achieve a similar HDR effect?**

Comment: Interesting topic. As far I know QGIS represents the pixel values between min/max with a linear function. The *fake* HDR can be achieve with a curve function (normally 3rd degree)  between min/max

Comment: Using a Graphic software to convert the imag before loading to QGIS is not an option?

Comment: I think it can more or less easily implemented with Python modules as OpenCV installed, see : https://learnopencv.com/high-dynamic-range-hdr-imaging-using-opencv-cpp-python/

Comment: @Babel This will turn the process into a nightmare =)

Comment: At least to my knowledge, HDR is used to increase the dynamic range of fotographs, but is not an establishe technique to use with remote sensing images. HDR always needs several different pictures (with different dynamic range) as input. Where do you have the idea from using HDR for your images? Can you link a ressource or is it an idea you had to increase somehow "visibility" of what you're looking for in the image? There are highly specialized tools for different tasks based on remote sensing images and I would first stick to these established methodologies - see my answer on Orfeo toolbox.

Comment: @Babel I took just the idea of HDR that all objects (both bright and dark) would be equally visible in the image. I am not an expert in this field. I have seen the use of such technology in computer games, photos and decided that they can be applied to satellite images.

Comment: "High-dynamic-range photographs are generally achieved by capturing multiple standard-exposure images, often using exposure bracketing, and then later merging them into a single HDR image, usually within a photo manipulation program." From https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-exposure_HDR_capture - so do you have several Images you can merge together?

Comment: Or are the Images already captured with highvdynamic range? If to both questions the answer ist no, you should Stock to other Methode to Make Details visible Like the tools in OTB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Orfeo Toolbox](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/), an open source libray specialized in image processing for remote sensing images. It can [be used in QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/otb.html) - see here [how to make it work](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html#otb-applications).

*For QGIS versions older than QGIS 3.8, see also the core plugin: activate it in Menu Plugin.*

There are a [lot of functions available](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications.html) - e.g. [Contrast enhancement](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_ContrastEnhancement.html) (see also [Enhance local contrast](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/recipes/contrast_enhancement.html) - cf. screenshot below), [Dynamic Convert](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_DynamicConvert.html). See also how to do for [Feature extraction](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/Feature_Extraction.html).

---

Just to illustrate how to get out more (visible) details out of the image you provided - see also the paper linked at the bottom.

*Local Statistic Extraction: the vegetation area is much more structured:*
[image]

*Contrast Enhancement - left: your initial example, right: output. Run the tool with different settings for parameters to find out the optimal setting:*
[image]

---

To achieve your goal, you must probably apply several steps. As we don't know exactly what kind of information you want to get, you should try what works best for you. A method based on

> image fusion method is utilized based on gradient pyramid
> decomposition and entropy weighting of different TDI stage images

is described in this paper: [Taiji Lan, Xucheng Xue, Junlin Li, Chengshan Han, Kehui Long: : A High-Dynamic-Range Optical Remote Sensing Imaging Method for Digital TDI CMOS, Appl. Sci. 2017, 7(10), 1089; https://doi.org/10.3390/app7101089](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/7/10/1089/htm)

Answer (score 11):

First of all, what you are trying to achieve is not HDR.
To attain (real) HDR one needs to have excess bit depth, and to discard in a meaningful fashion some bits.

For example, if you have a 3 channel (RGB) raw picture with 12 bit per channel, you can create a 8-bit-per-channel RGB picture. The trick is of coure that you discard high bits in some part of the picture and lower bits in other parts, thus bringing to life details which would otherwise go unnoticed.

## Blending Modes

Back to your need: I think you "just" want to stretch/enhance the dynamics of the Sentinel picture.
Currently in QGIS there is not such an option, at least that I am aware of.

## Overlay

You can obtain a more contrasted result by applying a `Overlay` Blending.

> Overlay combines Multiply and Screen blend modes.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpvjz.png) Where the base layer is light, the top layer becomes lighter; where the base layer is dark, the top becomes darker; where the base layer is mid grey, the top is unaffected. An overlay with the same picture looks like an S-curve. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Overlay))

In QGIS:

1. Duplicate the layer of the image (right-click -> `Duplicate Layer`)
2. Move it on top of the original layer
3. `Symbology` -> `Layer Rendering` -> `Blending Mode` -> `Overlay`
4. (optional) Set a transparency level to the copy layer. This will change the "pressure" of the Overlay effect.

[image]

The final effect will look rather close to your example:

[image]

## Screen

If, instead, you want to enhance the mid-range features, give a try to the "Screen" Blending Mode.

> With Screen blend mode, the values of the pixels in the two layers are inverted, multiplied, and then inverted again. The result is the opposite of Multiply: wherever either layer was darker than white, the composite is brighter.

[image]

## Side-by-side Comparison

[image]

You can then save the style of the copy layer and simply apply it again on the copies of other Sentinel images.
Since Sentinel images do not overlap, their copies' overlays will only apply to the original image extent.

Comment: I am grateful for such a comprehensive answer, but the actions you described only make it worse. In the original image opened in QGIS I do not see only objects in the shadow of the cloud. And as a result of performing the steps from your answer the surface of the ground illuminated by the sun becomes too dark and I can't see any objects on it.

Comment: I must have misundestood your question, then.. I thought that by "can distinguish between very bright objects ... and very dark objects", you wanted to have a more contrasted picture. Also the example picture before/after misled me. I will give it another try! :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, apparently I will need to experiment with the rendering settings and write my own plugin. Because duplicating layers and applying settings for a large number of them is labor intensive.

Comment: Would a Python script help you? How does your workflow look like? Do you first load all pictures or process them one by one?

Comment: I select 50-100 tif files in the folder and drag and drop them into the QGIS window.
After that, I manually adjust the display of each layer.
It would be more convenient for me to work if the images were rendered automatically, but I don't see how to do it the way you suggest, as this would lead to a doubling of the number of layers in the project. Apparently a plugin with additional rendering settings should help.

Comment: You could create a model for your workflow. That would be probably easier than Python code or creating your own plugin.